# Use glyphicons in fancytree (without plugin)

Tags: svg, glyphicons, fancytree

I saw the nice "glyph" plugin, but I have to assign to each node a different icon, depending on their attribute.

I saw also I can set the icon for each node with the icon attribute, for example: node.data.icon = "relativePathTo/myIcon.png".

How can I use bootstrap glyphicons linking them as if they were single image files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an open issue and will be implemented shortly. (See https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/306)